# Когда положение элемента матрицы на 1 месте, выводит неправильно. C++

Tags: c++, матрицы

Нужно вывести положения экстремумов в строке матрицы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
void out(int n, int m, int **mas)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            printf("%4d", mas[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n, m;
    int Min, Max, sum, *p, s, t, minj, maxj;
    char sim = '+';
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    while (sim == '+') {
        cout << "Введите число строк и столбцов\n";
        cin >> n >> m;
        int **mas = new int*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            mas[i] = new int[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
                mas[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            }
        out(n, m, mas);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            p = *(mas + i - 1);
            Max = *p;
            Min = *p;

            for (int j = 1; j <= m; ++j) {
                if (*(p + j-1) > Max) {
                    Max = *(p + j-1);
                    maxj = j;
                }

                if (*(p + j-1) < Min){
                    Min = *(p + j-1);
                    minj = j;
                }

            }

            cout << "\n\nМинимум: " << minj;
            cout<< "\nМаксимум: " << maxj;
        }
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "\n Продолжить? : ";
        cin >> sim;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы не инициализируете переменные `minj` и `maxj`. Если первый элемент экстремалный, присвоения соответствующей переменной не будет.

После

```
Max = *p;
Min = *p;
```

добавьте

```
minj = maxj = 1;
```

P.S. Если включить все предупреждения компилятора, он должен был сообщить о потенциально неинициализированных переменных `minj` и `maxj`. Вы видели это предупреждение?

Есть и еще одно - о неиспользованных переменных `sum`, `s` и `t`.